# Can I copy the packages needed for installing visual studio 2019 v16.2 to install it in another computer?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to copy all packages and files of installed visual studio 2019 v16.2 and use them in another computer to install visual studio without internet.

I read a lot about offline instalation and local cache but they are all about creating the scheme and then downloading packages from internet.

I want install it without internet?

What i need to copy, from any path and where to pate them in the other computer?

Comment: You can't do what you're asking. The installer has to be run, because it creates a lot of registry entries and folders, and copies many files to locations that the normal user doesn't have the ability to allow. Offlinie installation is what you need, whether you want it or not. It's the proper way to install without internet access.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm installing by installer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an offline installer.

See the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

If you want a *complete* offline installer, run:

```
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\VSLayout
```

This will download all the current workloads to create an offline install. Warning, it's going to be over 40GB in size.

You can then copy the VSLayout to a network drive or another computer and run the setup from inside that folder.